# float: left and float: right on the same line with different size text

Tags: html, css

I have a title and a nav menu that need to be aligned left and right respectively on the same line.

My research has told me that this can be done using `float: left` and `float: right` with `clear: both`.  This does work when the text is the same size, but when the title is a larger font size than the nav menu, the nav menu does not align with the bottom of the line, it aligns with the top like this:

```
_____     _____         ___ 
  |    |    |    |     |                                    Link 1    Link 2    Link 3
  |    |    |    |     |___
  |    |    |    |___  |___
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
_____     _____         ___ 
  |    |    |    |     |    
  |    |    |    |     |___
  |    |    |    |___  |___                                 Link 1    Link 2    Link 3
```

I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3a6Z/1/)

How can i get the nav menu to sit at the bottom of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your jsFiddle and made it right : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3a6Z/8/

Here are the main changes I've made in the CSS :

```
#menu
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height : 100px;    
    width: 160px;
}

#menu ul {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give them equal `height`s and then use `padding-top` on the `div` with the links -

Just remember to subtract the amount of `padding-top` from the `height` to maintain the same actual height.

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/gUFy8/1/ JSFiddle example

and here is an update to your fiddle. Added height to the title div, and height & padding to the menu div  http://jsfiddle.net/Z3a6Z/3/

you will need to play around with the amount of height & padding to get a perfect line-up.